# CSS size declarations

Tags: css, coding-style, standards

When defining size in margin/padding etc in CSS I often miss out 'px' for the value '0' e.g.

```
.myClass {
  5px 0 0 5px
}
```

I have recently been told by someone I work with to include 'px'

```
.myClass {
  5px 0px 0px 5px
}
```

Is there any advantages or disadvantages or either approach? or is this just preference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No disadvantages, you can use 0 without "px".

> A zero length may be represented instead as the  ‘0’. (In
>   other words, for zero lengths the unit identifier is optional.)

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths

Edit: also this question have been asked already

- [Size of zero pixels in CSS with or without 'px' suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359222/)
- [When specifying a 0 value in CSS, should I explicitly mark the units or omit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923042/)

Comment: I would agree with this. There is no difference. I personally however actually do use `0px` in most cases (i find it makes it easy to work with rendered pages in tools like Firebug where I might want to pop a 1 or something in front of it when editing in the CSS panel, when trying out various margins, padding, etc.

Comment: @MikeBrant This might be true, you have some developing comfort, if you do only have to change the value, but for a final version, i would use a tool like http://refresh-sf.com/yui/ to compress the css (this tool does remove units from zero-values by the way)

Comment: @r3bel Good comment.  Always a good idea to use a CSS compressor, particularly if you are working on an application where very byte matters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief overview about units in css, very useful as i think:

[css units (w3c)](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)

in general it is good to declare which unit you are using, while 0 is always the same, so you dont have to write the unit if you you have a 0-Value (zero) and there is no advantage if you do write the unit

(to the contrary, your css file is 2 bytes larger for each unnessecary unit you write, if not optimized :D)