# CSS minificator removes units for zero values (px, ms, em)

Tags: css, minify

In combres file, I use **defaultCssMinifierRef="msajax"**.

This minifier remove the units (px, em, ms) for all zero values.
But 0ms is not the same as 0s. 
So, what I should do, if I need to save units after minification?

Comment: What is the difference between `0` and `0ms`?

Comment: There is no diffrence difference between 0em, 0px and 0. The correct syntax is 0 without unit. What makes you think they're different?

Comment: Even though, units are not the same, a zero value still means.. zero, and in these cases, units are not relevant (whatever the unit is meant to mesure time or space).
Does your design break after minification? Do you have a problem with that?
Some more detailed description of your problem would help.

Comment: there's no difference except for frequency values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/frequency

Comment: Why is it a problem if the units are removed? Are you using JS which picks up the units from the CSS?

Comment: @İbrahimDuran *The correct syntax is 0 without unit.* That statement is incorrect. The units are unnecessary, but optional.

Comment: If the minifier removes the `ms`, it's buggy, and you should find another one.

Comment: @fcalderan Incorrect. It's true that frequencies do require units, but don't misinterpret that as meaning that **only** frequencies require units. For instance, time requires units.

Comment: the transition property requires time value because it can be either ms or s, so it must be specified, even for 0.

Comment: @Andrea CSS `calc()` also requires a unit on 0, else it fails. Seems like every minifier except Cloudflare has this issue ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unit identifier can be omitted only for **lengths** of zero. Other units require the unit identifier even for values of zero. Lengths include `em`, `px`, etc. There is some debate over whether it is better to include it or not (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359222/size-of-zero-pixels-in-css-with-or-without-px-suffix) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318471/property-0-or-property-0px-in-css)). A minifier will and should remove the unit identifier on lengths of zero. See the spec [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths):

> for zero lengths the unit identifier is optional

Non-lengths require unit identifiers, whether zero or not. If a minifier removes the unit identifier of a non-length, such as the `ms` in the time given as the value of the property `transition-duration`, it is a bug in the minifier.

Comment: So, the best way to resolve the problem is change minifier?

Comment: Yes. However, I haven't tested YUI compressor directly, but I did try some online version of it, and it **did not** remove the `ms`. Are you 100% sure it is removing `ms`, and not just length unit identifiers?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. I use msajax minificator. When I changed it to yui - issue was resolved.

Comment: But I should use msajax minifier, can you advise me how I can do this?

Comment: You are saying you are forced by company policy or something to use msajax minifier? Well, first, file a bug report. Then, try using `0.0000001ms`.

Comment: but I just downloaded it and it does **not** remove the time unit identifier. So could you please check again exactly what it is removing that you think it should not be?

Comment: The spec fails to mention that calc(0 + 24px) will fail in IE11. Some minifiers correct this issue by removing calc() from the final CSS (e.g. cssnano), but others do not (e.g. clean-css). See https://cssnano.co/optimisations/calc/

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever need to save 0 values with a unit.

In CSS using a 0 without a unit means the same as as 0 with unit.
You could use `top: 20px` and it would place the element 20px from the top depending on its position.

If you use `top: 0` this gets translated to `top: 0px` by the browser so you simply don't have to worry about that.

Your compiler will only strip the units off of the values like `0px`, `0em` because they are redundant and can simply be used as `0` instead.

If it were to strip off the value off a `top: 20px` for instance, this would cause problems since the rendering engine wouldn't know if it were `top: 20rem` or `top: 20px` which are remarkably different when compared.

Stripping units from 0 values with units is actually a bit of an advantage as less bytes have to be sent over the network, this is only very minor but since it's an automatic process it doesn't really cost you anything as a developer (as in keeping into account that you'll manually have to strip 0 values with units from their unit).

There are however exceptions to this as [@torazaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo) pointed out in the comments. Times in CSS e.g. `100ms`, `0.1s` require a unit but as [@torazaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo) pointed out this is also automatically handled by the minifier by shortening something like `100ms` to `0.1s` to save bytes.

Comment: According to [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/frequency):Zero values can be written without a unit only if there are <length> values, not <frequency>.
ms is frequency, so I need unit for 0 in this case?

Comment: This in incorrect. `transition-duration: 0;` is invalid, it is a time and needs a unit.

Comment: Also, your point about bytes on the network is irrelevant, since the minifier will strip/compress as necessary. For instance, a minifier will transform `0ms` into `0s` to save one byte while retaining the unit which is required for time.

Comment: @MarinaKolesnikova By the way, `ms` is **not** frequency, which something special (cycles/second), it is **time**. But time still needs a unit, such as `s` or `ms`.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks for pointing out the network issue, I've removed the incorrect comment and will edit the question with updated info.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks for clarification, this is realy what I need.

Comment: There is also a flexbox-bug in IE 10 / 11 where you need to specify a unit for the flex-basis value. E.g. `flex: 1 0 0px;`. See: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-4

Comment: Units are also required by calc(). In IE 11, calc(0 + 24px) will fail. Some minifiers correct this issue by removing calc() from the final CSS (e.g. cssnano), but others do not (e.g. clean-css). See https://cssnano.co/optimisations/calc/