# Inconsistencies with the display of metric notations in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, format, numeric

Just struggling a bit with the numeric notations in Highcharts.

I didn't like the default version with "k" for "thousands". So, while trying to change that, I stumbled over some inconsistencies (in my view; but perhaps/probably just a "I don't see the whole picture"-thing).

So, why does the zero value get the "k" extension too:

[image]

That doesn't make sense. There are no "0k", as there are no "0px" in HTML/CSS programming. It just should be "0".

Logically in that case, when I change the units to "thousands" or " 000"

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    numericSymbols: [" 000", " 000 000"]
  }
});
```

it looks like this:

[image]

Clearly: same thing, same false display.

So, I guess there is a solution to this, a work-around, or a misunderstanding. Can you help me? Thanks for any hints!

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/vXhDC/182/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`0px` and `0` are both the same in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318471/property-0-or-property-0px-in-css). `0k` seems fine as well when it is consistent with other values, but I guess you can see it differently.

To change this display you could `label.formatter` like:

```
  labels: {
    formatter: function(){
      return this.value === 0 ? 0 : this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
    }
  }
```

This will print "0" for `0` and same as without this code for the rest.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yup311dv/

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass `null` to the `numericSymbols` for the chart to display the full numbers:

`Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
      numericSymbols: null
    }
  });`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vXhDC/184/)

Comment: Ok. Good to know. However, another inconsistency there: There is a space for the thousand separator for the values "10 000" and above. But not for "5000"... Looks weird.